# How to prepend a certain value in a certain column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to prepend a certain value in a certain column in sql. I would want say "100_" prefixed and updated on foo.value. How should I go about doing this?

```
create table foo (id, value, ...)

insert into foo (1, 1);
insert into foo (2, 1);
insert into foo (3, 3);
insert into foo (4, 2);
insert into foo (5, 3);
insert into foo (6, 6);
```

Comment: "create table foo (id, value, ...)" would result in a syntax error.

Comment: Do you mean update the table data, or just result set data? Use concat and cast anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` column must be `varchar` datatype.

```
UPDATE Foo SET Value = '100_' + Value
```